# Watermark on table using CSS

Tags: css, image, html-table, watermark

I have to put a watermark each on  a series of receipts which are dynamically generated together a5 size. Using Rotativa  and asp.net mvc5.  These receipts are generated with tables unfortunately,  Not sure how to do this,

```
<style>
.watermark {
    height: 95%;
    width: 85%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0.2;
    }
</style>

<div class="watermark" style="background: url('/content/Images/image.png') no-repeat; opacity : 0.4;"></div>
<table>
</table>

<div class="watermark" style="background: url('/content/Images/image.png') no-repeat; opacity : 0.4;"></div>
<table>
</table>

<div class="watermark" style="background: url('/content/Images/image.png') no-repeat; opacity : 0.4;"></div>
<table>
</table>
```

......
Only one image is generated which stays at the top left of the first receipt.
I need help with this.

Comment: Try to put the div inside the table and put the table on `position: relative;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<style>
table tr td:first-child { background: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/21e3102a092c9848a19de0fd6f07b6ab?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");}
</style>
<table class="example-table">
  <tr><td>First column</td><td>Second column</td><td>Third column</td></tr>
  <tr><td>First column</td><td>Second column</td><td>Third column</td></tr>
  <tr><td>First column</td><td>Second column</td><td>Third column</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks supposing I want the image to cover only the first column area on the left